# How can I get the metadata from an mp3 file

Tags: javascript

Am trying to get the metadata of an audio file in javascript use jsmediatags but i get this error
`No suitable file reader found for [object HTMLAudioElement`.

Here is what I tried

```
const jsmediatags = window.jsmediatags

    let f = new Audio('/GabbyBarrett_I_Hope.mp3')

    jsmediatags.read(f, {
            onSuccess: function(tag) {
                console.log(tag)
            },
            onError: function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        })
```

Is there any other way to achieve this without manually getting the file like this?

````
const file = document.querySelector('.file')
    file.addEventListener('change', (e)=> {
    f = e.target.files[0]
        //console.log(f)
    
    
    jsmediatags.read(f, {
          onSuccess:function(tag) {
                console.log(tag)
            },
          onError:function(error) {
               console.log(error)
            }
        })
    })

```.
````

Comment: The library can't accept an Audio object. Read [the docs](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags) for the things it can support.

Comment: Okay i tried using the file like like this, ```let path = ''
f.onloadedmetadata = ()=>{
path = f.currentSrc
console.log(path)
jsmediatags.read('http://localhost:8158/GabbyBarrett_I_Hope.mp3', {
        onSuccess: function(tag) {
            console.log(tag)
        },
        onError: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
}``` but i get this error `Generic XHR error, check xhr object.` what can be done to resolve this. @user229044